# Swift Detect the position of a Button in UIView

Tags: swift

I can detect the button pressed in UIView through this simple code

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if let buttonRecognize = recognizer.view as? UIButton {
             let subviews = self.view.subviews as [UIView]
                    for v in subviews {
                        if let button = v as? UIButton {
                            if button.tag != -1  {
                               var p = button.superview?.convertPoint(button.center, toView: view)
                               println(p)
                }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(slideFactor * 2),
            delay: 0,

            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
            animations: {recognizer.view!.center = finalPoint },
            completion: nil)
        }}}}
}
```

As can detect the position of a button in UIView ?

> for (0,0) of Uiview = (367.666656494141,207.33332824707) for func handlePan

I would like to find the value of the button than the UIView where the center is that of UIView itself and not the value of func handlePan where the center is the top left corner !!

P.S. I tried to move the let subview etc after

```
completion: nil
```

but the result does not change !!

Comment: Can you be more specific, where and when would you want to detect that button?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a point coordinate system to that of the specified view using

> convertPoint(_ point: CGPoint, toView view: UIView?)

The toView is the coordinate system to which it will be converted.

Comment: i tried in this mode var p = button.convertPoint(button.center, toView: view)
                                    println(p.x) but i have always just the value of the function handlePan (E.g. 311) and not the value than the UIView (should be 0 to 311)

Comment: try: p = button.superview?.convertPoint(button.center, toView: view)